# try except, how to retry after exception error?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

im trying to use try and expect to update some values from API
this is the code which im using and i think its not working well, due to while its find error its filling all upcoming data with the same error value

`

```
new_budget = []
new_revenue = []
i = 42
start_time = time.time()
while len(new_budget) < 20:
    try:
        id = dfbudget['id'].iloc[i]
        response = tmdb.Movies(id).info()
        responsebdg = response['budget']
        new_budget.append(responsebdg)
        responservn = response['revenue']
        new_revenue.append(responservn)
        i += 1
    except:
        new_budget.append('test')
        new_revenue.append('test')
```

`

[image: Image from the result]

how can i handle the error once receiving HTTPError filling the data with 0 and retry to the next checking value

Comment: `i` never gets incremented if there's a fault prior to it, move it outside the `try/except` blocks and let it increment reguardless of the code succeeding or failing.

Comment: Also you have what is called a generic exception.  If the server response is 500, or 403, or you index is out of bounds, your code will happily churn forever.  You might want to look at handling the different possible types of errors in different manners.

Comment: @hww Thnx for your reply, but shall you explain how i will remove out of the loop and if its out of the loop based on what it will count for the next value if you can mention it in simple lines of code it will be appreciated

Comment: You should catch specific exceptions, and only put the code that can raise that exception in the `try` block. As a somewhat trivial example, do you really think that `new_budget.append('test')` would be an appropriate thing to try if `new_budget(responsebdg)` raised an exception? I think the only thing that could raise an exception you are prepared to deal with is the call to `tmdbs.Moview(id).info()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, when there's a HTTPError, the code flow jumps to the except block at that exact line. The code does not gets a chance to get to the 13th line where the `i` is getting incremented.

Since the value of `i` remains the same, it keeps on fetching the same value from the API and gets the same Error message for the rest of the loop.

So making sure that `i` increments, whether there's an error or not, would solve the problem. The following code should work.

```
new_budget = []
new_revenue = []
i = 42
start_time = time.time()
while len(new_budget) < 20:
    try:
        id = dfbudget['id'].iloc[i]
        response = tmdb.Movies(id).info()
        responsebdg = response['budget']
        new_budget.append(responsebdg)
        responservn = response['revenue']
        new_revenue.append(responservn)
    except:
        new_budget.append('0')
        new_revenue.append('0')
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thnx , already added the last condition for the i and solved appreciated